# jQuery AJAX succeeded, but $_POST is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This returns "Ok." alert and `array(0) { }`. How can I get jQuery `image` variable?

```
<script>
    var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: image,
        success: function() {
            alert('Ok.');
        }
    });
</script>

<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're posting to the same page via AJAX. On the original page you will still see `array(0) { }` but the page requested via AJAX will contain correct POST data in the response.

Also the correct code to submit `image` parameter is shown below.

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'image' : image },
    success: function(){
        alert('Ok.');
    }
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7spa13qe/) for demonstration.

Comment: @wavix, You're seeing `array(0){ }` because you're doing AJAX request which doesn't update the current page. In the response to AJAX request your page produces correct output, which can be verified using debugging tools of your favorite browser. Consider switching to form submission using POST if you want to see the output or adjust your PHP script to handle AJAX POST differently than regular GET. It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to upload an image to PHP Web server, via AJAX,
You need to have written your Web server to catch the Image data which you have sent.

I suggest you to follow two links:

1. [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30277217/1752988)
2. [Tutorial Link](https://subinsb.com/uploading-an-image-using-ajax-in-jquery-with-php)

Hope this may help you to get resolved your problem!

Cheers!

Comment: I don't want to upload an image. I want to use a jQuery variable in PHP, in the same page.

Comment: If you want to use a jQuery variable in PHP, then you may have sent it to the PHP Serverside!

Comment: Okay,
Try the following link and let me know, if it's correct for you I will update the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23583747/1752988

Comment: If I use, anywhere, `var_dump ($width)` returns the result in the console. It does not help.

Comment: Width is relevant to that answers particular question, but not to yours!
Please try to understand the given answer and try to resolve your problem!

Comment: On that example I used `var_dump($width)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it will get the variable at the server side

```
<script>
$.ajax({
        url: "//php serverside url",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
        //sucess    
        },
        error: function(){

   }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: My `$_POST` is still empty.

Comment: in the serverside it should be something like this `$image = $_FILE['file_field_name']['name']`

Comment: So as to get the image variable, which I think will be the value of the image variable